# background-image not displaying in Chrome or IE

Tags: css, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

The background-image works in Firefox, but not in Chrome or IE. I have tried several solutions on Stackoverflow, 
like turning off my ad-block, 
putting the same code in the head of the file,

```
<head><style>...</style><head>
```

putting the same code in the style attribute of the link,

```
<a style="..."> ... </a>
```

I have made sure there are no elements that are derived from the `appearance` attribute,
I have tried including the `background-attachment: fixed;` style
and finally I have tried to change:

```
background-position-y: 465px;
background-position-x: 5px;
```

To:

```
background-position: left center;
```

All of these variations on the below code work perfectly in Firefox.

```
.search-btn {
        padding-left: 32px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-image: url(../Images/search.png);
        background-position-y: 465px;
        background-position-x: 5px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

But not on Chrome or Internet Explorer.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="btn blue-btn mar-bot search-btn" OnClick="btnSearch_Click">Search</asp:LinkButton>
```

The other classes mentioned in the CssClass attribute in the order the appear in my CSS stylesheet:

```
.mar-bot {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.blue-btn {
  background-color: #55acee;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px #3C93D5;
}

.blue-btn:hover {
  background-color: #6FC6FF;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 5px);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.search-btn {
...
}
```

Comment: check the debug tools of chrome to see why, probably can not find the image.

Comment: @Aristos I checked, but according to Chrome it can find the image...

Comment: with out the actually page is hard to say. Maybe the `png` have the problem, try with jpg to see if works. Then if works try with different setting on png. Maybe you need to set width and height for the window to show that part of sprite. Probably with settings have to do, not with png...

Comment: You really don't have any errors in the dev-tools / firebug console? Could the uppercase in the path be the problem? (`../Images/search.png` vs. ../images/search.png). No more ideas, I suggest you to reproduce a simple test in jsFiddle, CodePen, so you can share it if it still doesn't work.

Comment: It wasn't the image location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.search-btn {
            padding-left: 32px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            background-image: url(../Images/search.png);
            background-position: left center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            display: inline-block;
        }
```

For some reason it needs `display: inline-block;` to work.
 I have no idea why this worked, but it does.